# Drop&Hide contents of table rows after sql query works only for the first row on asp

Tags: html, mysql

I have a database table called "flights". On an ASP page, I make a MySQL query and I'd like to put the results on a table. I am trying to make the rows clickable for further details. Here is my code..

```
<style>

    .dropbtn {

    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }


    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    padding: 4px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }


    .show {display:block;}
</style>
```

This is the query...

```
<%
Set records = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
records.open "SELECT * from flights WHERE flighttype='S' LIMIT 5 ",conn
%>
```

And here is the part that creates the loop and the table...

```
<table class="grid">
<tr class="capt alnl clrb">
<td>ID</td>
<td>Aircraft</td>
<td>Flight</td>
</tr>           
<%
while not records.eof 
%>
    <tr id="bdshow" onclick="openclose()" class="seq<%=no mod 2%> dropbtn">
    <td class="clrg"><%=records("idflights")%></td>
    <td class="clrg"><%=records("aircraftCode")%></td>
    <td class="clrg">Flight <%=records("flightNo")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <td colspan="3" class="alnc clrb fntb">
        <%=records("datearrival")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
<%
    records.moveNext
wend
records.close
%>
</table>
```

And finally this is the script...

```
<script>
function openclose()
    {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    var elem = document.getElementById("bdshow");

    }
</script>
```

This brings me the table just fine, but when I click on any row, only the first row brings the second line. You click on 5th row, but first row drops down with the first record's data. What should I do?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the main problem is that you use the identification label "`myDropDown`" for all dropdown-content rows. An "`id`" attribute in HTML must be unique across the entire document - and you have the same identification label in all rows. So naturally, only the first one "takes" and all the rest are being ignored.

What you'd want to do, is to have a unique `id` for each drop-down, pass it to the function on click and use it to locate the correct drop-down in the function. Fortunately, you likely already have a useful identification number: if your table has a row id column, as is customary, then you can just use that.

In the example below I'm going to assume that your numeric `auto_increment` row ID field is called `id`, so your updated ASP might look like this:

```
<table class="grid">
<tr class="capt alnl clrb">
<td>ID</td>
<td>Aircraft</td>
<td>Flight</td>
</tr>           
<%
while not records.eof 
%>
    <tr id="bdshow" onclick="openclose(<%=records("id")%>)" class="seq<%=no mod 2%> dropbtn">
    <td class="clrg"><%=records("idflights")%></td>
    <td class="clrg"><%=records("aircraftCode")%></td>
    <td class="clrg">Flight <%=records("flightNo")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="myDropdown-<%=records("id")%>" class="dropdown-content">
        <td colspan="3" class="alnc clrb fntb">
        <%=records("datearrival")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
<%
    records.moveNext
wend
```

and the script will have to take that numeric id and use it like this:

```js
function openclose(rowid)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown-"+rowid).classList.toggle("show");
    var elem = document.getElementById("bdshow");

    }
```

Comment: Now that I look at it a bit more, it seems that `idflights` is either your row ID column, or close enough to just work well enough.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot, you made my day. The solution works perfectly. I will keep this in mind. I appreciate, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. and now I have another problem, there are 3 columns on the table (shown on the photo), but when I drop a second line it only allows me to create one column, colspan doesnt take effect on the dropped line..